# Maven Shade relocated class calls non-relocated class

Tags: java, maven-shade-plugin

I am writing a custom module in order to integrate Kafka Connect with Hortonworks Schema Registry.

Both Kafka Connect and my module (more precisely HSR client library I am using) have `org.glassfish` dependencies. That is why, I relocated some dependencies to avoid class loading conflicts.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <relocations>
            <relocation>
                <pattern>org.glassfish</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.glassfish</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
            <relocation>
                <pattern>com.hortonworks</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>com.shaded.hortonworks</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
        </relocations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Surprisingly, it does not work as expected. The stacktrace below shows that relocated `com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient` class calls non-relocated `org.glassfish` class!

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.SchemaMetadata, genericType=class com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.SchemaMetadata.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:516)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:765)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:357)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient$15.run(SchemaRegistryClient.java:1079)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient$15.run(SchemaRegistryClient.java:1076)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.postEntity(SchemaRegistryClient.java:1076)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.doRegisterSchemaMetadata(SchemaRegistryClient.java:415)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.addSchemaMetadata(SchemaRegistryClient.java:398)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.registerSchemaMetadata(SchemaRegistryClient.java:390)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.addSchemaVersion(SchemaRegistryClient.java:443)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.addSchemaVersion(SchemaRegistryClient.java:431)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.serde.AbstractSnapshotSerializer.serialize(AbstractSnapshotSerializer.java:64)
    at com.shaded.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.serdes.avro.kafka.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:86)
    at com.example.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:60)
```

I double-checked I deployed the correct version of my jar.

Can anyone explain why it does not work? Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Grzegorz